# What action is taken by SO on rude and offensive comment

Tags: discussion, offensive

Given that my answer was down voted by another SO user. When asked for reason got very rude and offensive reply back

Just after a minute or so another user up votes the comments of previous offensive user and then gets completey rude

**So my question is what does SO do to these kind of unprofessional user after being reported, apart from deleting the rude comments made**

Comment: If it's repeated behaviour, the offenders get a telling-off, and if they don't mend their ways, suspensions.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks for replying, please see my comment below to minitech

Comment: Please keep in mind that people aren't required to explain a downvote. It's nice when they do so politely, but it's not a rule to explain.

Comment: You should link to the answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas I went an delete my answer that had offensive comments, because when as i reported the comments, that user went and deleted his comments out

Comment: @hat if the user doesn't have a pattern of rudeness, probably the most that would happen is that those comments would be deleted. You might consider undeleting since you know now that you can flag comments and explain the situation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's just one offense, the comment will probably get deleted, and that's that. People who are continuously rude can be sent a warning message and/or suspended, though.

Comment: thank you for replying, But in my case the second user logs in after and promotes the first user. So the point I am making is suspiciously looks like both user account are of the same individual

Comment: @HatSoft: Then flag that and explain your concerns in the "Other" box.

Comment: cool good idea, it did not came in my mind at that time may because of rage, thank you again