# Rename "About" to "New User? Click Here" for anonymous or new users?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, new-users, tour

Can we change the [About](https://stackoverflow.com/about) link on SE sites to "[New User? Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/about)" (or just "[New User?](https://stackoverflow.com/about)") for anonymous and "new" users?

"New" users would probably be something like

- Recently created account

  - Created less than X days ago (30?)
- Or low activity account

  - No upvoted questions or answers
  - Or fewer than X posts (3?)
- And no linked SE accounts with high reputation

Most "About" pages contain information about the website/company, such as their background/history, who runs it, the owners and staff, etc, and I would not think to check the "About" page of a website for new user information.

But I am always very happy to see [New User? Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/about) links on sites because I know the information contained in that link will be specifically for new users like me, so it will be written in a way I likely to understand and I won't waste my team reading through information I don't understand yet.

I think you will get more new users going to the new About page if you name the link more appropriately.

Comment: +1: This issue is linked to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172970/negative-comments-drive-new-users-away-how-can-we-fix-this, and a solution to this might be an answer to the linked question as well.

Comment: Aren't all new users shown the About page anyway? (Not that that takes away from the suggestion being a good one though)

Comment: @Bart I'm not sure about newly registered users, but it's not displayed anywhere when you go to SO as an anonymous user. And personally, if I am displayed an unwanted page that is preventing me from going to the page I am trying to go to, I am just going to bypass it as fast as possible. It would be better to make it easily found for users so that they can access it when they want it.

Comment: The about page is the first thing new users should see after they log in with OpenID or create a new account.  If that's not happening, it needs to happen.  Yesterday.  The real abomination is [faq].  What does that mean, anyway?  Fack. Ack. [cough].  Sorry, hairball.

Comment: We have several changes in the works to support new users, especially anonymous visiting for the first time.  You should see them soon.

Comment: @NickCraver Is this, or something like this, one of them?

Comment: @Rachel - it's a much better intro for anonymous users - you'll see it soon :) Jeremy, David, Jin and a few devs have been working on several changes to help anonymous users.

Comment: Well, no more "about" at all but rather "Tour" tab which redirects to the About page. @Nick think it's better status-something this one, not sure if completed or declined though.