# Can no longer ask, "What have you tried?" in comments?

Tags: discussion

I don't understand why we're not allowed to ask, "What have you tried?" in the comments section of a question. Can anyone explain this decision?

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKwdF.png)

Comment: [Shog covers the reason here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/182513)

Comment: @Bart, I find it funny that users consider these comments to be an "epidemic". Kind-of hyperbolic and stupid.

Comment: @mre Have you seen the screenshots?  Have you read the post???  Totally a problem and epidemic.

Comment: @Seth, Totally an opinion.

Comment: You have read the supposed duplicate I assume?

Comment: @Bart, Yes, I have. And I think the decision is pretty crappy.

Comment: Fair enough. Then we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Bart, Well apparently I'm being forced to agree.

Comment: Not really. You can disagree all you want. And if you have something constructive to add to the discussions, by all means go ahead and voice your disagreement. Whether that will change the situation depends on how convincing your arguments are.

Comment: @Bart, Smoke and mirrors

Comment: Suit yourself. If you are not willing to actually try and cause a change, don't be surprised to find that nothing changes.

Comment: I'm tempted to start flagging some of your comments as offensive and rude.  You can disagree, you can argue, but you can do it nicely.

Comment: @Seth, Do it. I'm not being offensive, I'm expressing an opinion. Sorry that you're taking offense to it.

Comment: @Bart, What do you think I'm doing right now?

Comment: @mre I am not going to argue.  *I* am not offended, but others might be and are.  You don't be nice because *you* feel like it, you are nice because you are thinking of *others*.  That is actually the main point behind this ban.  Just adding "What have you tried"  is neither constructive nor helpful or nice to the OP.

Comment: Complaining without arguments. Like I said, there are great questions arguing it's an epidemic. If you disagree and can constructively argue why you disagree, by all means contribute your thoughts in an answer to one of those posts. Those who thought there was a problem did so, and that had a result. There is no reason why you can't do so for the opposite point of view.

Comment: What have you researched before asking this Question?

Comment: @brasofilo, The research was discovering that I was unable to ask such a question, and providing proof. That's *what I have tried*.

Comment: @Bart, I'm sorry, but I feel like you're just full of hot air. I suppose SO is pushing me to just down-vote and close questions in which I find OP showing little to no effort. Cool. Done. Thanks, guys. Sorry newbies, no more being nice!

Comment: I think Bart's on the right track here. So far the main arguments I'm seeing in this question are "but I don't want to write anything else" and "blocking 'what have you tried' is stupid". I'm sorry, but those aren't really actionable.

Comment: @AnnaLear, My goodness how you misread everything that I say. Good riddance.

Answer (score 5):

Probably because it's very easy to abuse that comment. If it's obvious that OP hasn't even tried anything, there's a downvote button(please [see Shogs answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/164243) ).

Unfortunately people tend to mimic one another( I didn't even know that there were cases of multiple "What have you tried"'s in one post )  ...

Comment: New users are usually unaware that they need provide code, or show some effort on their part. I find these comments to be much more productive than a close or down vote.

Comment: @mre That's ridiculous.  How am I supposed to help you if you don't provide code or show effort??

Comment: @Seth, Although ridiculous, it happens quite frequently.

Comment: Sure, well you would want to elaborate on the comment.. if it's "please show code. i.e What have you tried?" it will pass thru

Comment: Have you read Shog's answer?  There is good reason for this blacklist.  It doesn't help anyone for you to just leave "What have you tried?".

Comment: @Seth, I beg to differ.

Comment: @mre I don't agree.  If it is a brand new user, then just leave something constructive showing them the features of the site, like the [faq] page or the [about] page or explaining how the site works in more than 4 words.  If you don't want to take the time, then downvote and walk away

Comment: @psubsee2003, How is downvoting and walking away constructive? Such backwards thinking.

Comment: @mre what is more constructive... `what have you tried?`, or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554292/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-text-messages#comment22042834_15554292)

Comment: @psubsee2003, It's just a more verbose version of "What have you tried?". And they're both equally effective IMHO.

Comment: @mre yes it is... you made my point.  I actually explained something to the user.  What have you tried just feeds into the perception that Stack Overflow is unfriendly to newbies.

Comment: @psubsee2003, That's an overly broad statement. Each user is different..not all are hyper-sensitives.

Comment: @mre If you don't want to take the time to elaborate and don't want to downvote without commenting, you can also just walk away and look at another question instead. There's plenty to go around.

Comment: @AnnaLear, And what if I find the question interesting, but am reluctant to provide information until OP shows a little effort or that they put some thought into the problem? What then?

Comment: @mre This is [my last point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172970/182513).  If PHD students are afraid to post, then maybe we need to think about how we approach new users.

Comment: @mre Use your best judgement. Your comment reads to me like you hesitate to post an answer to a question you deem "unworthy". Answering questions and teaching folks how Stack Overflow works are two different things. If you want to answer something, answer it. If you don't, don't.

Comment: You can add a nice *constructive* comment pointing the user in the right direction.

Comment: @psubsee2003, And asking "What have you tried" is an inappropriate approach that will scare new users away? Get real.

Comment: @AnnaLear, I just don't believe in spoon-feeding answers.

Comment: @Seth, It is both *constructive* and **nice**.

Comment: @mre Not spoon-feeding answers is totally fine. Mind you, I don't think "what have you tried" is a problem in and of itself. It's a nice enough question. However, this is a case of a *lot* of people misusing it to the point where it's easier to just disable it than try to yet again explain to that just *maybe* posting multiple comments that all say "what have you tried?" on the same question isn't even remotely helpful or nice.

Comment: @AnnaLear, So, you guys are of the mindset of punishing all for the actions of the few? Good to know.

Comment: @mre I'm having trouble seeing this as a punishment, to be honest.

Comment: @AnnaLear, Because not everyone uses that question with the intention of being a d*ck. It is helpful and has a purpose.

Comment: @mre I'm sure that most, if not all, people don't. It ends up coming across that way anyway.

Comment: @AnnaLear, Haha wow..

Comment: @mre - Perhaps you should just make a proper feature-request that comprehensively fixes it.  I think we can probably find a workaround of some sort, between totally banning "What have you tried" and allowing multiple "What have you tried" comments within a post.   That said, it's easy enough to overlook this annoyance - you can type "What have you tried, buddy" and it passes :p

Comment: @Adel, Are SO filters really that dumb? I guess I shouldn't be surprised after reading all these responses.

Comment: @Adel, And that justifies its stupidity? LOL

Comment: @mre - Hey in principle i agree that we shouldn't ban one specific phrase... but people started being sophomoric and acting too silly.  'Tis is life

Comment: @AnnaLear, Are you honestly implying that the intention of this feature is to spare the feelings of newbies, despite the functional use of such a question? Hahaha I find that both incredibly funny and sad.

Comment: @Adel, Pandora's box, man.

Comment: @mre - It's just life, I personally don't really like the 15 second commenting timeout.. but I get it. Get why it's there

Comment: @Adel, Now you're comparing Apples to Oranges. Totally not relevant.

Comment: @mre - OK ya i know, i'll drink coffee first :-)

Comment: @Adel, You go do that. I'm gonna get loaded on cough syrup.